# Investigating variables in the VS C++ Debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Having the debugger stopped at an `breakpoint` what does the value of the `Value` field corresponding to the variable name shows?

[image]

Is it just an address of the string in the memory?

Comment: What's the exact type of `message`, `message1`, etc? Are they `std::string`s or are they `const char*` C-style strings? In the latter case it's certainly an address in memory, that's what a pointer is.

Comment: @Nathan Pierson It's what's the `c_str()` method of `std:string` returns so it's `const char*`.

Comment: Well, there you go. A `const char*` _is_ a pointer to a `const char`, so its value is an address in memory. There's additional things you can get from it, like knowing that it's actually pointing to the first member of a null-terminated array of characters, which the debugger also shows. But most immediately its value is an address because it's a pointer.

Comment: You can also copy the address into the memory inspection window if you want to see the raw storage at the address pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is the memory address of the first character.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    std::string q= "hello world";
    const char* p = q.c_str();

    printf("%p \n", &p[0]);
    printf("%p \n", &p[1]);
}
```

[image]